# Returning a pointer to a char array inside a struct in C?

Tags: c, arrays, return

I have the following struct in the header file:

```
static FILINFO fno;
```

Which looks like so:

```
typedef struct {
DWORD   fsize;      /* File size */
WORD    fdate;      /* Last modified date */
WORD    ftime;      /* Last modified time */
BYTE    fattrib;    /* Attribute */
char    fname[13];  /* File name */
} FILINFO;
```

Now I would like a certain function to return a pointer to fname[] which should be possible since the struct is defined static. Here is my function:

```
char* get_open_file_name (void)
{
    return fno.fname;
}
```

I'm calling this function from main like so:

```
char* temp;

int main (void)
{
    intialize_sd_card ();
    ...
    ...
    temp = get_open_file_name();
```

This results in conflicting types error message. However if I try to call it like so:

```
char* temp = get_open_file_name();
```

It works. What am I missing here?

EDIT:
Here is the actual error msg I'm getting from GCC

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning     assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Comment: I suggest you share the error message (although I think someone that's not in about to go to bed now like me, could probably spot that nevertheless). :)

Comment: @gsamaras OK, added

Comment: Sounds like you did not declare the function before calling it? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but could something like this be at play here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char fname[4];
} FILINFO;

static FILINFO fno;

char* temp;

char* get_open_file_name(void) {
    return fno.fname;
}

int main(void) {
    fno.fname[0] = 'L';
    fno.fname[1] = 'o';
    int temp; //my awesome hidden debug value, with regards, previous dev
    fno.fname[2] = 'l';
    fno.fname[3] = '\0';
    if(1 /*or whatever*/) {
        temp = get_open_file_name();
        printf("%s\n", temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Owing to local-scope visibility rules, this frankenstein can be legal - that up to the point where the char pointer is to be casted to an integer, of course. Then if You replace `temp = get_open_file_name();` with `char* temp = get_open_file_name();`, it will work fine.

Once the offending debug value is gone, the following compiles and runs flawlessly, using GCC 9.2.0 with `-s -O3 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char fname[4];
} FILINFO;

static FILINFO fno;

char* temp;

char* get_open_file_name(void) {
    return fno.fname;
}

int main(void) {
    fno.fname[0] = 'L';
    fno.fname[1] = 'o';
    fno.fname[2] = 'l';
    fno.fname[3] = '\0';
    temp = get_open_file_name();
    printf("%s\n", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your guess was right! The header file that included the static struct had an int temp variable for debugging and * I guess * since the header was included before the declaration of the char* temp in main.c it ended up never "seeing it".